# Creating a new tab from boostrapped extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm having some trouble creating a new tab from inside a bootstrapped extension in Firefox. So far I have an extension that draws a few buttons for the context menu that can open modal windows on click with `windows.open()` like this :

```
        var contextMenu = document.getElementById("contentAreaContextMenu");

        var menuItemWebsite = document.createElement("menuitem");
        menuItemWebsite.setAttribute("id", "dev-website");
        menuItemWebsite.setAttribute("label", "Go to website");

        contextMenu.appendChild(menuItemWebsite);
        menuItemWebsite.addEventListener("command", function() {
          window.open(...);
        }, false);
```

There are very few resources on the web on restartless extension. Can anyone provide an example of opening a new tab to a specified URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a window first then you can open new tab in it.

This example here gets the most recent navigator window and adds a tab to it:

```
const {classes: Cc, Constructor: CC, interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu, results: Cr, manager: Cm} = Components;
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var aDOMWindow = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
aDOMWindow.BrowserOpenTab()
```

another way to do this is use gBrowser.loadOneTab:
so:

```
aDOMWindow.gBrowser.loadOneTab(aDOMWindow.BROWSER_NEW_TAB_URL, {relatedToCurrent:true});
```

this opens the tab next to the currently focused tab.
more info on it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Method/loadOneTab

There are these other useful functions:
`OpenBrowserWindow`

Comment: My pleasure. If you got anymore bootstrap questions post them up. Bootstrap is my speciality and I can't help much because so many people are going towards SDK. :(

Comment: Don't worry, I have a few I'll ask soon. Are there any books on the subject though?

Comment: MDN and MXR and then forums like stackoverflow and ask.mozilla.org and mozillazine.org and mozilla addon forums. MDN and MXR should be enough, but i always need help so I use the forums.

Comment: This works but I am little confused. `getMostRecentWindow` returns `nsIDOMWindow` (which inherits from `nsISupports`). The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMWindow) for `nsIDOMWindow` does not mention `BrowserOpenTab` or `gBrowser` as one of the methods/properties. Then where are these coming from?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure either I've just been using it for years haha @oyenamit just kidding, each DOMWindow has a tabbrowser element in it, this is referenced by gBrowser, check out the tabbrowser docs